# How to redirect to another page and fire an event on that page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to redirect to the another page in the same project and fire click event automatically. I am able to redirect to another page, but need help on how to fire the event automatically. The class from where i am redirecting is called `Testing and the class to which i redirect is`TabTest`. My code in the`Testing` class is:

```
  protected void LinkButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      Response.Redirect("TabTest.aspx");
  }
```

Comment: I edited your question to make it clearer, but I might have done something wrong, changing the meaning. Can you please check through that this version says what you want? Otherwise update it using the edit link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly fire the event on redirection.

A solution is to add a query string parameter to the redirect:

```
Response.Redirect("TabTest.aspx?ShowChart=true");
```

In the `Page_Load` event of TabTest.aspx, add the following code:

```
if(Request.QueryString["ShowChart"] != null 
  && Request.QueryString["ShowChart"] == "true"))
{
    // Call the click event handler for the button that shows the chart. Passing
    // `null, null` assumes that you don't use the sender or eventargs parameters
    // in the event handler.
    ShowChart_Click(null, null);
}
```

Comment: i have a link button on the tabtest.aspx page which show chart on click event i want to redirect to the tabtest page and fire click event of link button to show chart automatically as it redirected ?

Comment: @Syed Raza: Updated the code to clarify according to your comment.

Comment: i try to do it but when i debug it it is redirecting to the tabtest page i use break point on if condition before load event but it is not catching it it keeps on redirecting to the another page?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a QueryString (which a user could manually type in themselves) I would recommend passing a Session variable like the following. I'm afraid my c# knowledge is non-existent, but here is a VB.NET equivalent:

FirstPage.aspx

```
Session("mySession") = "myValue"
Response.Redirect("TabTest.aspx?FireSession=1")
```

TabTest.aspx

```
If Request.QueryString("FireSession") = 1 AndAlso Session("mySession") IsNot Nothing AndAlso Session("mySession") = "myValue" Then
  RunMethod()
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not fire the event in the page_load? you could stick it within a check on postback so it doesn't fire more than once?

Answer (score 0):

You need to encapsulate the Chart display method into a separate method say like `DisplayChart()` and call up these method based on some QueryString parameter or just call it in the page_load of the TabTest.aspx

Avoid invoking a handler directly, Event handlers should only be invoked as a consequence of an event being fired, its better to call this method in the handler also.